Problem calling deriv function on fd objects
I'm studying the book "Functional Data Analysis with R and MATLAB" using R and the R package fda and I have a small problem replicating Figure 1.12. It's very easy to fix it (see below) but I don't understand the underlying issue.
A reprex of the problem:
library(fda)
#> Loading required package: splines
#> Loading required package: fds
#> Loading required package: rainbow
#> Loading required package: MASS
#> Loading required package: pcaPP
#> Loading required package: RCurl
#> Loading required package: deSolve
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'fda'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     matplot

# Create an fd object represeting the weather in 4 canadian stations
fig1.11Stns = c('Montreal', 'Edmonton', 'Pr. Rupert', 'Resolute')
fig1.11Temp = CanadianWeather$dailyAv[
  , 
  fig1.11Stns, 
  'Temperature.C'
]

Temp.fourier   = create.fourier.basis(c(0, 365), 13)
fig1.11Temp.fd = Data2fd(day.5, fig1.11Temp, Temp.fourier)
class(fig1.11Temp.fd)
#> [1] "fd"

# Define a linear differential operator
yearRng      = c(0,365)
Lcoef        = matrix(c(0,(2*pi/365)^2,0),1,3)
harmaccelLfd = vec2Lfd(Lcoef, yearRng)

# Compute the derivative according to the linear differential operator
deriv(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd) # fails
#> Error in deriv.default(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd): invalid variable names

# However, when I explicitly call the S3 method, everything works fine
deriv.fd(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd) |> plot()


#> [1] "done"

Created on 2024-08-26 with reprex v2.0.2
Why is there an error when I call the generic deriv but there is no error when I explicitly call the S3 method for fd objects?
A few notes:

the code (up to the last line) is taken from the companion scripts of the book, which are available inside the folder named scripts within the downloaded R package: system.file("scripts", package = "fda"). In particular, I'm using the script named fdarm-ch01.R.
I manually added the last line (i.e. deriv.fd instead of deriv).


From what I understand, R automatically loads package {stats}, among others, on startup. {stats} then registers as handler of deriv calls. Even though {fda} has an internal default (inspect with fda:::deriv), this default will "only" UseMethod to dispatch to what is considered prior scope for calls to deriv, which is where {stat} takes over (see namespace shown by find("deriv")).

Thank @I_O for your comment. However, I still don't understand why stats::deriv does not dispatch to fda::deriv.fd

Agila, I don't have a deep understanding of R's scoping, so maybe s/o more experienced can help out. AFAIK it goes like this: R receives a call to deriv. {stat}, as one of the "privileged" packages, grabs the call but gets no derive.default from {fda} anyway (expand fda:::, triple colon!, with tab to check absence of such). So it's back to which default {stat} can find, which is its own. BTW, thanks for the hint to FDA, sounds really interesting.

It seems this is because the {fda} package does not register its deriv.fd() S3 method as one might expect.
If you look at the NAMESPACE, you will find this line:

S3method(deriv, fd)

The above NAMESPACE line is registering fda::deriv.fd() with the fda:::deriv() generic because fda:::deriv() is found before stats::deriv() "as seen from the package" (see this blog post). However, fda:::deriv() is not exported from the package.
The effect of this registration and lack of export is that the fda:::deriv() generic will not show up on the search path via library(fda). Therefore calls to deriv() as in your code use the stats::deriv() generic which does not know about the fda::deriv.fd() method.
If the fda:::deriv() generic was exported, when you library(fda) the fda::deriv() generic would take precedence over the pre-existing stats::deriv() generic, and R could then dispatch the call to fda::deriv.fd() based on the class of the first argument according to S3 dispatch.
I am unsure if this is intended behavior or not on the part of the package authors. To me the presence of a fda:::deriv() generic suggests the authors intended to export. As Ben suggests, you might consider contacting them for clarification.
There are a number of ways to change this behavior. Here are seven off the top of my head to illustrate the S3 registration and search path issues at hand:

Call fda::deriv.fd() S3 Method Directly
Call fda:::deriv() Generic Directly
Copies in Global Environment
Register fda::deriv.fd() with stats::deriv()
Fork and Export fda:::deriv() Generic
Fork and Remove fda:::derive() Generic
Fork and Register fda::deriv.fd() with stats::deriv()

1. Call fda::deriv.fd() S3 Method Directly
Bypass the S3 issues altogether and call fda::deriv.fd() directly as you did.
library(fda)

# Create an fd object represeting the weather in 4 canadian stations
fig1.11Stns = c('Montreal', 'Edmonton', 'Pr. Rupert', 'Resolute')
fig1.11Temp = CanadianWeather$dailyAv[
  , 
  fig1.11Stns, 
  'Temperature.C'
]

Temp.fourier   = create.fourier.basis(c(0, 365), 13)
fig1.11Temp.fd = Data2fd(day.5, fig1.11Temp, Temp.fourier)
class(fig1.11Temp.fd)
#> [1] "fd"

# Define a linear differential operator
yearRng      = c(0,365)
Lcoef        = matrix(c(0,(2*pi/365)^2,0),1,3)
harmaccelLfd = vec2Lfd(Lcoef, yearRng)

# Compute the derivative according to the linear differential operator
deriv(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd) # fails
#> Error in deriv.default(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd): invalid variable names

# call fda::deriv.fd() directly
deriv.fd(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd) |> plot()


#> [1] "done"

Created on 2024-08-28 with reprex v2.1.1
2. Call fda:::deriv() Generic Directly
You could call fda:::deriv() directly:
library(fda)

# Create an fd object represeting the weather in 4 canadian stations
fig1.11Stns = c('Montreal', 'Edmonton', 'Pr. Rupert', 'Resolute')
fig1.11Temp = CanadianWeather$dailyAv[
  , 
  fig1.11Stns, 
  'Temperature.C'
]

Temp.fourier   = create.fourier.basis(c(0, 365), 13)
fig1.11Temp.fd = Data2fd(day.5, fig1.11Temp, Temp.fourier)
class(fig1.11Temp.fd)
#> [1] "fd"

# Define a linear differential operator
yearRng      = c(0,365)
Lcoef        = matrix(c(0,(2*pi/365)^2,0),1,3)
harmaccelLfd = vec2Lfd(Lcoef, yearRng)

# Compute the derivative according to the linear differential operator
deriv(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd) # fails
#> Error in deriv.default(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd): invalid variable names

# call fda:::deriv() generic
# for which fda::deriv.fd() has been registered via NAMESPACE
fda:::deriv(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd) |> plot()


#> [1] "done"

Created on 2024-08-28 with reprex v2.1.1
3. Copies in Global Environment
You could make copies of fda:::deriv() and fda::deriv.fd() in global:
library(fda)

# Create an fd object represeting the weather in 4 canadian stations
fig1.11Stns = c('Montreal', 'Edmonton', 'Pr. Rupert', 'Resolute')
fig1.11Temp = CanadianWeather$dailyAv[
  , 
  fig1.11Stns, 
  'Temperature.C'
]

Temp.fourier   = create.fourier.basis(c(0, 365), 13)
fig1.11Temp.fd = Data2fd(day.5, fig1.11Temp, Temp.fourier)
class(fig1.11Temp.fd)
#> [1] "fd"

# Define a linear differential operator
yearRng      = c(0,365)
Lcoef        = matrix(c(0,(2*pi/365)^2,0),1,3)
harmaccelLfd = vec2Lfd(Lcoef, yearRng)

# Compute the derivative according to the linear differential operator
deriv(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd) # fails
#> Error in deriv.default(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd): invalid variable names

# place a copy of fda:::deriv() generic in global
deriv <- fda:::deriv
# and a copy of fda::deriv.fd() so that the new generic can find the fd method
deriv.fd <- fda::deriv.fd

# call your global deriv() generic
# - the global deriv() generic is found before stats::deriv() generic due to being defined in global environment
# - the global deriv() generic can find deriv.fd() due to it also being defined in the global environment
deriv(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd) |> plot()


#> [1] "done"

Created on 2024-08-28 with reprex v2.1.1
4. Register fda::deriv.fd() with stats::deriv()
You could use registerS3method("deriv", "fd", deriv.fd) to register fda::deriv.fd() with stats::deriv():
library(fda)

# Create an fd object represeting the weather in 4 canadian stations
fig1.11Stns = c('Montreal', 'Edmonton', 'Pr. Rupert', 'Resolute')
fig1.11Temp = CanadianWeather$dailyAv[
  , 
  fig1.11Stns, 
  'Temperature.C'
]

Temp.fourier   = create.fourier.basis(c(0, 365), 13)
fig1.11Temp.fd = Data2fd(day.5, fig1.11Temp, Temp.fourier)
class(fig1.11Temp.fd)
#> [1] "fd"

# Define a linear differential operator
yearRng      = c(0,365)
Lcoef        = matrix(c(0,(2*pi/365)^2,0),1,3)
harmaccelLfd = vec2Lfd(Lcoef, yearRng)

# Compute the derivative according to the linear differential operator
deriv(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd) # fails
#> Error in deriv.default(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd): invalid variable names

# register fda::deriv.fd() S3 method with stats::deriv() generic
registerS3method("deriv", "fd", deriv.fd)

# call stats::deriv() generic
# - stats::deriv() generic is found before fda:::deriv() generic because fda:::deriv() is not exported and therefore not on search path
# - fda::deriv.fd() is registered to stats::deriv() via registerS3method()
deriv(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd) |> plot()


#> [1] "done"

Created on 2024-08-28 with reprex v2.1.1
5. Fork and Export fda:::deriv() Generic
You could fork the source and add export(deriv) to the namespace file.
I have done so for you here.
# install patched version
remotes::install_github("the-mad-statter/fda@export-deriv-generic")

library(fda)

# Create an fd object represeting the weather in 4 canadian stations
fig1.11Stns = c('Montreal', 'Edmonton', 'Pr. Rupert', 'Resolute')
fig1.11Temp = CanadianWeather$dailyAv[
  , 
  fig1.11Stns, 
  'Temperature.C'
]

Temp.fourier   = create.fourier.basis(c(0, 365), 13)
fig1.11Temp.fd = Data2fd(day.5, fig1.11Temp, Temp.fourier)
class(fig1.11Temp.fd)
#> [1] "fd"

# Define a linear differential operator
yearRng      = c(0,365)
Lcoef        = matrix(c(0,(2*pi/365)^2,0),1,3)
harmaccelLfd = vec2Lfd(Lcoef, yearRng)

# call fda::deriv() generic
# - fda::deriv() generic is found before stats::deriv() generic because fda::deriv() generic is now exported via NAMESPACE and therefore on the search path before stats::deriv() generic due to library(fda)
# - fda::deriv.fd() is registered to fda::deriv() via NAMESPACE
deriv(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd) |> plot()


#> [1] "done"

Created on 2024-08-28 with reprex v2.1.1
6. Fork and Remove fda:::derive() Generic
You could fork the source and remove the fda::deriv() generic from the package.
I have done so for you here.
# install patched version
remotes::install_github("the-mad-statter/fda@remove-generic")

library(fda)

# Create an fd object represeting the weather in 4 canadian stations
fig1.11Stns = c('Montreal', 'Edmonton', 'Pr. Rupert', 'Resolute')
fig1.11Temp = CanadianWeather$dailyAv[
  , 
  fig1.11Stns, 
  'Temperature.C'
]

Temp.fourier   = create.fourier.basis(c(0, 365), 13)
fig1.11Temp.fd = Data2fd(day.5, fig1.11Temp, Temp.fourier)
class(fig1.11Temp.fd)
#> [1] "fd"

# Define a linear differential operator
yearRng      = c(0,365)
Lcoef        = matrix(c(0,(2*pi/365)^2,0),1,3)
harmaccelLfd = vec2Lfd(Lcoef, yearRng)

# call stats::deriv() generic
# - fda:::deriv() has been removed from package
# - fda::deriv.fd() is registered to stats::deriv() via NAMESPACE
deriv(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd) |> plot()


#> [1] "done"

Created on 2024-08-28 with reprex v2.1.1
7. Fork and Register fda::deriv.fd() with stats::deriv()
You could fork the source and change S3method(deriv, fd) to S3method(stats::deriv, fd) in the NAMESPACE file.
I have done so for you here.
# install patched version
remotes::install_github("the-mad-statter/fda@register-with-stats")

library(fda)

# Create an fd object represeting the weather in 4 canadian stations
fig1.11Stns = c('Montreal', 'Edmonton', 'Pr. Rupert', 'Resolute')
fig1.11Temp = CanadianWeather$dailyAv[
  , 
  fig1.11Stns, 
  'Temperature.C'
]

Temp.fourier   = create.fourier.basis(c(0, 365), 13)
fig1.11Temp.fd = Data2fd(day.5, fig1.11Temp, Temp.fourier)
class(fig1.11Temp.fd)
#> [1] "fd"

# Define a linear differential operator
yearRng      = c(0,365)
Lcoef        = matrix(c(0,(2*pi/365)^2,0),1,3)
harmaccelLfd = vec2Lfd(Lcoef, yearRng)

# call stats::deriv() generic
# - fda:::deriv() is not exported and therefore not on search path
# - fda::deriv.fd() is registered to stats::deriv() via NAMESPACE
deriv(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd) |> plot()


#> [1] "done"

Created on 2024-08-28 with reprex v2.1.1

Agreed. It wouldn't hurt to e-mail the maintainer about this, though ...

Thank you very much! Could you add a bit more details explaining why the (currently) unexported fda::deriv function interferes with the regular S3 dispatch? My (probably wrong) understanding is that when I call deriv() on fd objects, then I'm actually calling stats::deriv (which is an S3 generic) and that should dispatch to fda::deriv.fd (which is exported and the S3 method is properly registered). Why my reasoning is wrong? In any case I will get in contact with the maintainer as soon as I figure it out!

I would argue fda::deriv.fd() is not properly registered. At the very least, it is not registered like you expect. As it currently stands, fda::deriv.fd() is registered to fda:::deriv() via the NAMESPACE file, but the later is not exported from the package. Therefore, in your original code, when you run deriv(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd), you are indeed calling stats::deriv(), but this generic does not know about the fda::deriv.fd() method. In essence there are two generic functions in play, but you can only easily access one of them. Please see my edits for further clarification.

Thanks, perfectly clear! Just a couple more questions if possible (I can also open a new post if needed): 1) Is there any benefit on redefining the deriv S3 generic within the package? Because, IMO, solution #6 is the most sensible one. 2) When I load the current CRAN version of fda and run methods("deriv"), I see that deriv.fd is among the outputs. Is that correct given the considerations listed in your answer? Or is that a bug in methods()?


When I rely on S3 in my packages, I use either solutions #5 (export generic) or #6 (no generic). When I have employed #5 it was because there was no existing generic outside my package (e.g., gdotk::report() which has registered methods to format the results of some statistical tests in APA format). When I have employed #6 it was because I was extending the ubiquitous print() method for a new class in my package (e.g., wubik::print.init_script()). So I think the choice whether to include a generic in your package is dependent on whether one already exists and your desired behavior.


1 cont.) If no generic already exists, you will need to define and export a generic. If a generic already exists, you may be happy with allowing that generic to deal with dispatch. However, I can also envision situations where you might want to override the existing dispatch pattern by defining and exporting a generic even when one already exists. An example being that you wish to deter users from accidentally applying the wrong method - especially if your package often gets loaded alongside other packages that have overlapping dispatch.


I am not sure I understand things well enough to label the inclusion of "deriv.fd" in the output from methods("deriv") as a bug, but I certainly also find it confusing. Note that if you ?methods you can read this note: "The S3 functions listed are those which are named like methods and may not actually be methods ...". So it seems our expectations for the function may be incorrect.


Thanks for all. Great explanation. btw: I opened a new issue in the fda github repo: https://github.com/JamesRamsay5/fda/issues/11

Here is that package's github: https://github.com/cran/fda/blob/master/R/deriv.fd.R
And also for further information please check page 79: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fda/fda.pdf
I just checked from their github.
deriv <- function(expr, ...) UseMethod('deriv')

deriv.fd <- function(expr, Lfdobj=int2Lfd(1), ...)`
They used deriv() as an interface for deriv.fd(). You are getting invalid variable names erro because deriv expects expression and other arguments. But when you use it as deriv. It doesn't fits to true parameters. So if we just skip deriv and use deriv.fd instead of it like that
deriv.fd(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd)

It will work as like that. If you want to wrap it into deriv then just overwrite it as an function which uses deriv with deriv.fd then
Here is the final solution:
library(fda)
#> Loading required package: splines
#> Loading required package: fds
#> Loading required package: rainbow
#> Loading required package: MASS
#> Loading required package: pcaPP
#> Loading required package: RCurl
#> Loading required package: deSolve
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'fda'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     matplot

# Create an fd object represeting the weather in 4 canadian stations
fig1.11Stns = c('Montreal', 'Edmonton', 'Pr. Rupert', 'Resolute')
fig1.11Temp = CanadianWeather$dailyAv[
  , 
  fig1.11Stns, 
  'Temperature.C'
]

deriv <- function(expr, variable) {
  return(deriv.fd(expr,variable))
}

Temp.fourier   = create.fourier.basis(c(0, 365), 13)
fig1.11Temp.fd = Data2fd(day.5, fig1.11Temp, Temp.fourier)
class(fig1.11Temp.fd)
#> [1] "fd"

# Define a linear differential operator
yearRng      = c(0,365)
Lcoef        = matrix(c(0,(2*pi/365)^2,0),1,3)
harmaccelLfd = vec2Lfd(Lcoef, yearRng)

# Compute the derivative according to the linear differential operator
deriv(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd) # fails
#> Error in deriv.default(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd): invalid variable names

# However, when I explicitly call the S3 method, everything works fine
deriv.fd(fig1.11Temp.fd, harmaccelLfd) |> plot()


Hi and thanks for your answer! I know I can use deriv.fd instead of calling deriv but, in my opinion, that feels unsatisfactory within the S3 framework and I would like to understand why the S3 dispatch fails.

This GitHub repo is only marginally useful; it's not a repository set up by the package maintainers. It is instead a mirror of the package code that's available on CRAN. (So posting issues, pull requests, etc. on this repo will be useless.)

This seems to be the source repo.
